# Spring Scheduler synchronized method starvation

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, deadlock, starvation

Assume I have a scheduler

```
@Component
public class Scheduler{

    private static int counter = 0;

    private synchronized void countIt(){
        counter++;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 3000)
    public void job1(){
        countIt();
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 6000)
    public void job2(){
        countIt();
    }
}
```

Different task trigger in different case will call countIt.

When two or more job call countIt simultaneous, it will cause starvation.

Could any one tell me if there is a way to avoid this situation?

Comment: does not look like a case for deadlock

Comment: @AdamSkywalker the real case is a little complicated. I have lots of threads call this synchronized method. When they call the method in the same time, deadlock happened.

Comment: deadlock is a situation when thread 1 holds resource A and needs resource B, and thread 2 holds resource B and needs resource A. synchronized method is a mutex, alone it can't cause a deadlock

Comment: maybe your thread got stuck inside a method and other threads are waiting for it, but it's not a deadlock

Comment: At the most, this could cause starvation, but not a deadlock.

Comment: @AdamSkywalker I think I use a wrong word, as Haroldo_OK figure out, it is starvation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no deadlock here!

**Use ReetrantLock with Fair policy.** if u dont know ReentrantLock please google it.

```
private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);
```

Comment: It seems what I looking for, Let me try it first

Answer (score 0):

This should not deadlock.

A Deadlock is caused by one thread locking resource `A` and then attempting to lock resource `B` while another thread locks resource `B` and then tries to lock resource `A`. There are more complex ways a deadlock can occurr but deadlocks cannot happen with only one lock.

In your case there is only one lock so there is no deadlock.